# Kubernetes CPU quotas and process scheduling behavior

Tags: kubernetes, kernel, quota, cfs

Given a Pod defining a container that runs a single-threaded application, and a CPU limit value of `1`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: single-threaded-workload
spec:
  containers:
  - name: microservice
    image: single-threaded-workload
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
```

Would the single-threaded application ever be CPU throttled?

Would increasing the CPU limit value to higher than `1` provide any performance benefit?

(This is assuming the container only has 1 active thread running)

Answer (score 2):

CPU limits are not actually related to the available CPUs on the machine, but to the CFS (Compute Fair Scheduling) which is a mechanism used to determine how much CPU time can process consume. In short, `limits: 1 CPU` means that your process can consume the whole scheduler period (by default 100ms), it does not matter whether it consumes the whole period on a single CPU (1x100ms) or  2 half-periods (2x50ms=100ms) on two CPUs.
It is quite well explained in this article: https://wbhegedus.me/understanding-kubernetes-cpu-limits/